# Matplotlib memory error with pandas dataframe having a datetime64[ns, UTC] index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-datetime

I have following pandas data frame with "time" field of datatype datetime64[ns, UTC] as a **INDEX** and "intensity" of type float64.

[image]

The data frame just consist of 10 rows. Still when I am calling the function `df.plot` or `plt.show()` then it gives the one of the following errors:

1. **MemoryError: Unable to allocate 447. GiB for an array with shape (59996093697,) and data type int64**
2. **Or driver crashes and system restarts.**

Library version and Environment:

- Environment: Jupyter Notebook
- Library versions pandas==1.4.1 and matplotlib==3.5.1.

Please let me know if someone else has faced this problem and how did you resolve it.

You can reproduce this problem with following steps:

```
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
print(df.dtypes)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
print(df.dtypes)
df = df.set_index("time")
df.plot()
```

output.csv contains following lines:

```
time                                 intensity
2014-08-14 05:49:55+00:00           -17624170.29
2014-08-14 05:49:55.003906250+00:00 -19298497.11
2014-08-14 05:49:55.007812500+00:00 -17602197.3
2014-08-14 05:49:55.011718750+00:00 -16704962.77
```

Comment: Could you please try to add the type of each column?

Comment: @Phoenix I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `floor` your index:

```
df.index = df.index.floor('S')
```

Comment: No not working. Its taking ages to plot the data and I have to interrupt to avoid driver failure.

Comment: Can you share your date or it's confidential?

Comment: I am getting dates from a EDF file. I don't know what format it is in EDF but I am using this function to convert it to pandas dataframe raw_edf.to_data_frame(picks=['intensity'], time_format='datetime').

Comment: Without your date, I can't try to reproduce your problem. Try to write `df` as csv `df.to_csv('output.csv')` and reload it with `df = pd.read_csv('output.csv')`

Comment: when I write to csv and again read it then I am able to plot it. But I found that the column was as string. However when I converted it to datetime then again same problem.

Comment: I have added sample data and code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same bug but when I `floor` the index, it works as expected

Comment: You can also use `df.resample('S').mean()`